# Wordpress AMP plugin eror: The attribute 'type' may not appear in tag 'style amp-custom'

Tags: css, wordpress

Wordress uses AMP plugin. Currently getting error `The attribute 'type' may not appear in tag 'style amp-custom'.`

When opening up the page and visiting console, the error points to the style attribute `type`.

```
<style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

This section of code comes from the `index` page. How would I go about changing this? Where can I change the wordpress code? Is this a theme error and therefore would I need to contact the theme developer?

Answer (score 0):

## **Here's an example**

```
      <!doctype html>
    <html amp lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello, AMPs</title>
        <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
        <script type="application/ld+json">
          {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "NewsArticle",
            "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
            "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
            "image": [
              "logo.jpg"
            ]
          }
        </script>
        <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
        <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Welcome to the mobile web</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: how does this help me though? how can I update wordpress with this new code? Is this code in the theme or can I update it manually?

Comment: @Mlennie My bad, I missed the wordpress tag, I don't like wordpress so I'm not sure how is done there, but seeing your style tag it should be like this:  <style amp-boilerplate>